# Display a loading page until the website has fully loaded in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Goal: Display a loading page until all of my components are fully loaded.

Question: Will this `useEffect` achieve what I am hoping for, or will it only complete the `useEffect` and then return the children regardless if they're loaded or not?

I'm unsure of how to test this code without using a setTimeout. Is my code correct, or is this not going to work as I'm hoping?

How can I better implement this?

App.js:

```
    const App = () => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

    useEffect(() => {
    setLoading(false);
     }, []);

    return (
     <Loading loading={loading}>
      <NavBar />
      <Home />
      <About />
      <Technology />
      <Project />
      <Contact />
    </Loading>
     );
      };

export default App;
```

Loading.js

```
const Loading = ({ loading, children }) => {
  return loading ? (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#191919",
        height: "100vh",
        width: "100%",
      }}
    >
      <Box sx={{ width: "40%" }}>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>Loading...</h1>
        <LinearProgress />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  ) : (
    children
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `useEffect`, by definition, will run as soon as your elements (this `<Box` in `Loading` in your case as you set up your components) are mounted on the DOM. If the goal in your actual code is fetching some data like from an API and then calling `setLoading(false)`, it's fine.

Otherwise, it's kinda you are listning to [`DOMContentLoaded`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event), which means that if you have some image or video on your page, there is no guaranty that it's already loaded and displayed. If you want that, use the [`load`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event) event, like so:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    const removeLoader = () => setLoading(false);
    window.addEventListener("load", removeLoader);
    return window.removeEventListener("load", removeLoader);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {loading && <Loading />}
      <NavBar />
      <Home />
      <About />
      <Technology />
      <Project />
      <Contact />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

```js
const Loading = () => {
  return (
    <Box
      sx={{
        display: "flex",
        justifyContent: "center",
        alignItems: "center",
        backgroundColor: "#191919",
        position: fixed;
        inset: 0;
        z-index: 999;
      }}
    >
      <Box sx={{ width: "40%" }}>
        <h1 style={{ textAlign: "center", color: "white" }}>Loading...</h1>
        <LinearProgress />
      </Box>
    </Box>
  );
};
```

Make sure `Loading` is fixed via CSS to cover the other components being loaded underneath it.

Comment: Regarding the use case, I am definitely looking for a solution to handle image loading (as stated in the second paragraph). 

Can you explain why you placed the code inside of a useEffect inside of another useEffect? I haven't tested this code yet, but as soon as I do I will accept it.

Comment: Hi Sam! The `useEffect` thing was by mistake. I just edited my answer.

Comment: Great, I'll test it tonight.

Comment: Hid @SamLevine, where are you with it? Could you give it a try?